# Making a CSS3 animation more reliable among browsers

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this CSS3 animation working on codepen.

**HTML**

```
<div class="heart heart1"></div>
<div class="heart heart2"></div>
```

**CSS3**

```
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.heart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fc2e5a;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.heart:after {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin :100% 100%;
}
.heart1{
   animation: heart-anim 1s linear .4s infinite;
}
.heart2{
   animation: pounding .5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.heart1:after, .heart1:before{
  background-color: #ff7693;
}

@keyframes pounding{
  0%{ transform: scale(1.5); }
  100%{ transform: scale(1); }
}
@keyframes heart-anim {
  46% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  52% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(50);
  }
}
```

Check it here: http://codepen.io/RadValentin/pen/sfnCE

As you can see is working ok, BUT, if I post the exact code to my local server OR to jsfiddle it does not work any more: http://jsfiddle.net/40aydbfr/

I believe the animation is not made according to the best practices since it breaks very easily.

So, Why it does not work outside of codepen and how can I make it more cross browser compatible.

PS: Im using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are missing vendor prefixes for `-webkit-` browsers.

The reason why it works on codepen is because, if you click on the settings button above the CSS window, you'll see that **-prefix-free** is enabled, which means it adds the prefixes automatically.

[Always check browser support, if something doesn't work](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes).

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxBpoe)**

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40aydbfr/1/)**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.heart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fc2e5a;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.heart:after {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.heart1 {
  -webkit-animation: heart-anim 1s linear .4s infinite;
  animation: heart-anim 1s linear .4s infinite;
}
.heart2 {
  -webkit-animation: pounding .5s linear infinite alternate;
  animation: pounding .5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.heart1:after,
.heart1:before {
  background-color: #ff7693;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pounding {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes pounding {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes heart-anim {
  46% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  52% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(50);
  }
}
@keyframes heart-anim {
  46% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  52% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(50);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heart heart1"></div>
<div class="heart heart2"></div>
```